# Angular boolean values from child to parent

Tags: angular

I have one child component, which have a particular html code and I want to show it for certain parent components only. I followed below method but it didn't work for me

```
child.ts
 button = true

    child.html
    <div *ngIf="button">
    ..........show/hide me 
    </div>
```

...........................................................

```
parent.ts
    @Input()button

    ngOnInit(){
    this.button = false}

    parent.html
    <child [button]="button"></child>
```

"..........show/hide me"  should not be render in parent. but its there

Answer (score 0):

Mistake is in the child component.

```
button = true
```

needs to  be

```
@Input() button = true
```

refer to this
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-niuksv